# How come one of my columns in bootstrap is not functioning properly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a site for my high school robotics team and I am completely new to html and css. How come one of the columns (the member 10 one) is not functioning like the others?

It seems one of the columns is off center. I'm not sure exactly how to describe it but I can post an image if necessary.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Robotics Team</title>

<!-- Link to stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index1.css">


<!-- Mobile Scaling -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
<!-------------------- UNIFORM CODE ------------------------->
<!-- Navbar -->

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home">Team 3774</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 0.866667px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/Team Bio">Team Bio</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Our Robot">Our Robot</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Our Coach">Our Coach</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Outreach">Outreach</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Youtube">Youtube</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Banner -->
<div id="top-jumbotron" class="jumbotron">
    <img src="/Images/Banner.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
<!----------------------------------------------------------->


<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Team Member Bio</h1>
    <p>Here you can find links to every member with some information on each of them.</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="bubble">
            <h2>Member 1 </h2>
            <p>Team Captain, Engineer, Coder</p>
            <a href="/Team Bio/page1.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="bubble">
            <h2>Member 2</h2>
            <p>Head Engineer, Assistant Captain</p>
            <a href="/Team Bio/page2.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="bubble">
            <h2>Member 3</h2>
            <p>Head Coder, Head Web-master</p>
            <a href="/Team Bio/page3.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="bubble">
            <h2>Member 4</h2>
            <p>Coder, Head Documenter</p>
            <a href="/Team Bio/page4.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="bubble">
            <h2>Member 5</h2>
            <p>Engineer, Head 3D Modelling</p>
            <a href="/Team Bio/page5.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="bubble">
            <h2>Member 6</h2>
            <p>Coder, Web-master, Engineer</p>
            <a href="/Team Bio/page6.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="bubble">
            <h2>Member 7</h2>
            <p>Financial Advisor, Engineer</p>
            <a href="/Team Bio/page7.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="bubble">
            <h2>Member 8</h2>
            <p>Engineer, Documenter</p>
            <a href="/Team Bio/page8.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="bubble">
            <h2>Member 9</h2>
            <p>Engineer, Coder</p>
            <a href="/Team Bio/page9.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="bubble" id="special">
            <h2>Member 10</h2>
            <p>Secretary, Mascot</p>
            <a href="/Team Bio/Page 10.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>





#top-jumbotron
 {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

body
{
background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

.bubble
{
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 20px;
width: 95%;
height: 175px;
border-radius: 15px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#special
{
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Page is http://www.robotichive3774.com/Team%20Bio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a /div - I notice you have a div inside a div, remember you need to close both. I use Netbeans for html and it will tell you if there is a problem. If you are on a Mac, I am told Komodo is really good, too. A good editing program is a life saver!

Fixed code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="bubble">
            <h2>Mina Hanna</h2>
            <p>Engineer, Coder</p>
            <a href="/Team Bio/Abanoub.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
        </div>
</div> <!-- this one! -->
```

**edit** there are a few things wrong with the code and michael points one out - as he says, Bootstrap is a grid. So Imagine (I actually draw it usually) a box split into 12 columns. For every row div, you should only have columns that add up to 12 inside it. You can break this and it will often still work because the div will just overflow and move down, but it's not best practice. If fixing the missing div end tag doesn't work, try fixing the row structure so it only adds up to 12 columns across the page

Answer (score 0):

You can have a layout like the one you specify, however it wont necessarily work per Bootstraps intended functionality, and as such its usually a good idea to follow their recommended row structure.

Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases.

Instead of

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

You should do, e.g:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>

</div>
```

Within a row, the sum of the numbers following the hyphen in each column definition should add up to 12.